# how to upload Visual Studio code on codeplex or Git?

Tags: c#, git, codeplex

I need to upload a visual studio code on git / codeplex . 
how can i do that? on source code option at codeplex , it is showing fork something ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install git on your local machine, create a local git repository, commit the changes and then push the changes to your remote git. http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Visual Studio Tools for Git](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) VS plug-in. You will need to also install [Git](http://git-scm.com/downloads) locally. Lastly you will need to configure in VS the repository you will be uploading to and, once configured, commit and push.